# Finding the maximum of a ratio of binomial coefficients

Tags: inequality, optimization, binomial-coefficients

Let $0 \leq d \leq K \leq D_L \leq 100$, with $K$ and $D_L$ fixed.

How can I see that
$$\dfrac{\displaystyle\binom{100-D_L}{K-d}\binom{D_L}{d}}{\displaystyle\binom{100}{K}}$$
is maximized when $d$ is minimized?

Unfortunately, all I've done is written out the definition $$\binom{n}{r} = \dfrac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$$
for the three above binomial coefficients, and I'm stuck there.

Comment: Let's say you have $100$ marbles from which $D_L$ are black and the rest are white, and you want to pick $K$ marbles. The expression you wrote is equal to the probability of the case where exactly $d$ marbles are black. My intuition says that this probability is maximized when
$$\frac{d}{K}=\frac{D_L}{100}$$
maybe because it is more likely for an inherited set to have the same structure as its parent.

Answer (score 1):

You ask for the maximum value of your expression with respect to $d$.

Let us name your expression

$$
B(d) = \dfrac{\displaystyle\binom{100-D_L}{K-d}\binom{D_L}{d}}{\displaystyle\binom{100}{K}}
$$

Then we have the quotient, after evaluating the factorials:
$$
Q(d) = \frac{B(d)}{B(d+1)} = \frac{(d+1)(101-D_L - K + d)}{(D_L - d)(K-d)}
$$

The claim is that the maximum of $B(d)$ will be obtained at some value of $d$ which we may call $d_m$. 
This is equivalent to (1) having that $Q(d) > 1$ for all $d \ge d_m$ and 
(2) having that $Q(d-1) < 1$ for all $d\le d_m$

Starting with (1), $Q(d) > 1$ is equivalent to 
$$
 (d+1)(101-D_L - K + d) > (D_L - d)(K-d)
$$
or
$$
d > \frac{-101 +K + D_L (K+1)}{102} 
$$

With the same argument, for (2), $Q(d-1) < 1$ is equivalent to

$$
d < 1 + \frac{-101 +K + D_L (K+1)}{102}
$$

So both conditions give the solution, rounding to the next highest integer, 
$$
d_m = \lceil{\frac{K D_L + (-101 + K+D_L)}{102}} \rceil
$$

*Some discussion:*

For large $K$ and $D_L$, the approximate value is $K D_L / 100$, as expected (see also the comment by polfosol).

For not so large numbers of $K$ and $D_L$, the linear term $(-101 + K+D_L)/102$ induces small shifts.

We will not always obtain positive values for $d_m$, since $d_m$ becomes zero for $-101 +K + D_L (K+1) <0$ or

$$
 D_L  < \frac{101 - K}{K+1}
$$